# How to toggle content in a div and change content in another div, on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

So this is for a home renovation site..
I have 2 columns, on the left side I want thumbnails of each property and on the right side is where the property images/description will be displayed when a property's thumbnail is clicked.. but at the same time I also want it to toggle a div under the thumbnail that was clicked to display mini "before" and "after" thumbnails. I want these only to display when the thumbnail is clicked and disappear either when it is clicked again or if another property's thumbnail is clicked, and of course then the before and after pictures for that property would display underneath... I can do this part with css and jquery and I found a way to change the content in the div based on which image is clicked.. but I cannot seem to do both at the same time....

I hope I'm explaining this right...

made a jsfiddle thingy https://jsfiddle.net/jeni/g1dhocyw/

this is the css i used to toggle the before and after pics

```
.collapse{
font-size: 31px;
display:block;
}
.collapse + input{
display:none;
}
.collapse + input + *{
display:none;
}
.collapse+ input:checked + *{
display:block;
}
```

I found a jsfiddle and messed around with it so it does what i want.... http://jsfiddle.net/jeni/8eqsbhet/ but when i try to incorporate it into my other jsfiddle the css stuff doesn't work

halp meh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the checkboxes to radio.

`<input id="_1" type="radio" name="xyz">...`

And updated the last "for" and "id" that had the value "_2" to "_3".

`<label class="collapse" for="_3">`

`<input id="_3" type="radio" name="xyz">`

See revision here: https://jsfiddle.net/3kqq2yx5/

---

Update:

Revised with jQuery Code: https://jsfiddle.net/3kqq2yx5/2/

Comment: thank you! This worked great! Although I have a question.. how can i make the 1st thumbnail show the default content.. because right now the default content and the 1st thumbs content are the same.. i want to just combine them.. so it isn't so redundant. And because when i add an array it only works for the default content but if the 1st properties thumbnail is clicked it no longer works..

Comment: Sorry, Jeni. I'm a bit uncertain about what you're trying to say. If you want the first thumbnail to be the default, check this: https://jsfiddle.net/3kqq2yx5/3/. Let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: Yeah, that's perfect. Thank you! :)